# build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o Error 1 при сборке cpp в NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

Я установил NetBeans, MinGW, написал для теста код, он отказывается собираться. Kод:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
cout << "test";
return 0;
}
```

вывод:

```
cd 'C:\Users\Йожек\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=    
SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/ 
�����/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk 
dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/ 
�����/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o 
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/ 
�����/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/ 
�����/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 2s)
```

Извините, если вопрос тупой, я здесь недавно. В гугле решения не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предположить, что виноваты русские символы в пути к проету.

> Не используйте неанглийские буквы и пробелы в путях. Это общий совет
>   для всего, что связано с программированием — это позволит избежать
>   многих проблем - [ixsci](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15146/ixsci)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/303224)

Comment: @Axenow, кстати, с огромной долей вероятности кириллица в пути и привела к сбою. 2SKIP, но лучше было написать это комментарием к вопросу.